# Appending/updating issue in real time when splicing from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I am currently working on an application using socket.io, ARI_Client(Node.js) and JQuery.

I have a slight issue at the moment where I am able to have values change based on whats in the array in real time, everything works when am adding stuff to the array........but not so much when am removing them, I have to refresh the page for it to work.

When I only have a single value in the array and splice that same element it works, any more than that then the values swap place on the web page and when I refresh the original desired effect is there.

**Update sip function.**

How am passing the data back to the client.

```
function updateSip() {
  console.log("Value: " + test);
  io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
}
```

**Splicing the array and calling the function.**

```
function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
    console.log(util.format(
        'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
    console.log(channel.name);

    var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
    chanArr.splice(index, 1);
    updateSip();
  }
```

**Appending to the webpage.**

```
Query(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $sip = $('#sip');

    socket.on('sip', function (data) {
        var sip = '';
        $( "#exe" ).remove();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sip += data[i];
        if(sip){
        $sip.append('<tr id="exe">\
                                    <td>'+ sip +'</td>\
                                    <td><btton class="btn btn-default mute" id="mute" type="submit">Mute</button></td>\
                                <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kck" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                    </tr>');
        }
        else{
            $sip.append('Currently no extensions');
        }
        sip = '';
        }

    });
```

For a bit more clarity on what happens I will link screenshots.

Single value in the array, if I remove/end call it will splice it from the array and the webpage in real time.

[image: Single value]

If there is more than two values in the array, the two values you see below swap and that's it, but when I refresh the page the element that was removed from the array can no longer be seen.

[image: More than one value]

I need it to remove at all times in real time, and am unsure as to why it works for a single value and not more than one.

Comment: `$( "#exe" ).remove();` you know this removes only one element even if there are many right? You need to use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: Oh well....that's embarrassing, that was indeed the issue, @guramidev do you want to post an answer so you can get the credit for it.

Comment: no it's ok, glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided by @guramidev the issue was using an ID instead of class which involved only ever removing one element at once even if there are many.

```
$( "#exe" ).remove();
```